# ASP.NET MVC GET forms with localized data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got an ASP.NET MVC HTML form for a search page - based on GET, including a localized date field.

The model binder for query strings uses invariant culture, therefore model binding fails if the localized date is not compatible with the invariant culture.

What's Microsoft's solution to the user story "my search form should be model binded correctly".

At the same time it would be nice to still be able to send those GET links to other users with other culture settings.

I guess you have to send the input culture along with the query string and write a custom model binder. Is this really the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

In form submit, extract a culture-neutral representation of the date field (`toISOString()`, `toUTCString()`, `valueOf()`), and store it in a hidden field.

Comment: I guess my "not-so-nice" solution (sending the language in the query string) is better as we do not need to utilize JavaScript. Thanks for your answer though.